# Cast icon not showing for custom receiver

Tags: android, chromecast

I have followed the CastHelloText-android example on github.  When I use either the receiver they specified in the demo or the default receiver, the cast icon shows up in my application.

However, as soon as I change the app_id to be the one provided by the Google Cast SDK Developer Console for my registered application, the icon doesn't show.

I've tried rebooting my chromecast and my android device. All to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Comment: As a note to anyone else coming here, this issue can also be caused by adding a new custom receiver and not restarting your testing ChromeCast. Upon restart, the cast icon should appear.

Comment: Unplugging and plugging back in my Chromecast worked. (Before this I hadn't restarted it since before registering it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the serial number for the device that you have registered on the dev console is correct, it is sometimes hard to read the serial number (take  a picture and zoom in). Also make sure the checkbox that sends the serial number is checked when you setup you chromecast. If cast icon doesn't show up for your own app-id but shows up for the other one, then there is an issue with your app/device registration.

Comment: That was it!  I had a number "0" instead of a capital letter "O" for one character.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as Kimble above. I started with the serial number on my Nvidia shield, which didn't work because that's not the serial number for the Chromecast. The proper serial number can be found in the settings menu under "Chromecast built-in".

Answer (score 1):

I know I am late to the party, but here is a probably more up-to-date solution. Following this documentation solved my problem: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/registration#find_device_serial_number

According to the documentation, for cast-enabled Android TVs, the serial number can be found in the following way:

> Android TV (ATV) devices have multiple serial numbers associated with them. The software (Cast) serial number can be obtained either by casting the Cast Developer Console page to the ATV device as outlined above, or by putting the ATV device into developer mode and looking in the Cast settings for the software serial number.
>
> To put your ATV device into developer mode, navigate to **Settings > System > About > Android TV OS build**, and click on the build several times until the device notifies you that you are in developer mode. To find the serial number once in developer mode, navigate either to **Settings > Device Preferences > Chromecast built-in** or **Settings > System > Cast**, depending on your ATV model, and you'll see the software serial number displayed.

[image: chromecast settings screen shot]

Also, since just by looking at the screen there is no way to disambiguate zero and capital O, or small L and capital I, etc., you can simply cast the page in the link above to read out the serial number for you:

> To find the serial number of any device, you can cast the Cast Developer Console page to the device:
>
> 1. Click the Cast button (as if you were casting this page).
>    The prompt displays Cast tab and lists the available devices.
> 2. From the drop-down menu, select the device for which you want to obtain the serial number.
>
>    - For display devices, the serial number displays on the TV screen and is read aloud on the TV speakers (to help disambiguate 0's and O's).
>    - For audio devices, the serial number is read aloud on the speaker being cast to.

Comment: To be clear you will need to cast https://cast.google.com/publish (the "Google Cast SDK Developer Console", the documentation is a little ambiguous and refers to it as "Cast Developer Console page".